# I keep getting the shopping cart is empty....?

Tags: php, forms, paypal

Where am I going wrong? the company email is correct I tried using the merchant Id but still no joy.....??

```
<?php $items = unserialize($_SESSION['items']); ?>
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"> 
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">  
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="cherished4ever@hotmail.co.uk">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.cherished4ever.com/">   

<?php
$suffix = 1;
foreach($items as $item):
?>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_<?php echo $suffix; ?>" value="<?php echo $item['name']; ?>"> 
<input type="hidden" name="amount_<?php echo $suffix; ?>" value="<?php echo      $item['price']; ?>"> 
<?php
$suffix++;
endforeach;
?>
```

---

Ok so i have got it working now however I just need some help with the checkout page showing the option name and not the item_name value set as the hidden output:

```
<select name="amount" style="width:150px;font:9px;margin-top:4px">
<option value="35.00">10 x 10</option>
<option value="55.00">20 x 20</option>
<option value="75.00">30 x 30</option>
</select><br>
```

Comment: Do you have a `session_start();` anywhere?

Comment: And where are you creating $_SESSION['items']?

Comment: no I dont... shall I stick that at the top of the page where the form is?

Comment: That is all the code I have...and all of the items are on a form within that form

Comment: Yes, if you're using sessions, be sure to include session_start(); on any page that uses the $_SESSION variables.

Comment: Adam, I put in <?php
session_start();
?>

Comment: Did that fix the problem? I don't understand where the items are coming from...  You don't have any code where the $_SESSION['items'] variable is being set?

Comment: I literally have that code and that is it...do i need to create a new page? I have a list of items such as the following:

Comment: <input type="radio" name="item_name" value="10x10">10 x 10 - &pound;15.00
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="15.00">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">

Comment: I have this sittin at the top of my page:

<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['items']

?>

Comment: Bascially, I want the form data to be sent to the users paypal shopping cart, check out the page im working on

http://cherished-4ever.co.uk/

Comment: I'm sorry, honestly I'm not familiar enough with the PayPal API.  I don't think $_SESSION is what you want, though.  It looks like you may not be passing the correct stuff to PayPal.  Should you be passing a hidden field like amount_22 to paypal? How will they know which radio button that's associated with?

Comment: Thet exact code works if I switched it to _xclick instead of _cart it sends that information to the paypal checkout page...

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like? Can you include this?

Comment: Robert, check out the source if you can I would be most greatful and tell me where iv gone wrong:

http://cherished-4ever.co.uk/

Or atleast point me in the right direction...

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to remember your `session_start();` at the top of each page that uses the `$_SESSION` variable.

For more information, take a look at: http://www.php.net/session_start